# logstash: find out the top users

Tags: logstash

I want to know whether I can get the top 5 active users through logstash and visualize it in Kibana.
the log file looks like this:

```
2016-02-18 13:58:30,924 comment_created=csearch, user=user107@mail.com, text=csearch
2016-02-18 13:58:35,522 highlight_created, user=user107@mail.com, text=the
2016-02-18 13:58:36,346 highlight_created, user=user107@mail.com, text=kage
```

in this example the user 'user107@mail.com' has made several activities and I wanna know whether logstash can filter that. At least to show that this is one of the most active users.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer using this filter:

```
kv {
    fields => "user"
    field_split => ","
    }
```